# Mysql Bug on Limited Rows

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, limit

i've a strange bug in MYSQL (innoDB tables).

I've the following table: (users)
surname (varchar) | name (varchar) | fiscalCode (char 16) | toUpdate (bool - int 1) | type (enum SSN | STP) | status (A = alive | D = dead) | lastUpdate (datetime)

Here the query select:

```
SELECT fiscalCode FROM users
WHERE type = 'SSN' AND toUpdate = 1 AND status = 'A'
ORDER BY lastUpdate ASC LIMIT 100
```

Doing this, I get 100 fiscal code but if I verify them, someone has `toUpdate = 0` and someone has `lastUpdate` with a date and in the DB there are a lot of `lastUpdate = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'` so using `ORDER BY lastUpdate ASC` I expect that as first

If I turn the query using `*` as fields, so:

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE type = 'SSN' AND toUpdate = 1 AND status = 'A'
ORDER BY lastUpdate ASC LIMIT 100
```

I get the right results. With all `fiscalCode` with `toUpdate = 1`, `status A`, `type SSN`, and `lastUpdate '0000-00-00 00:00:00'`.

Why? It is a bug of Mysql?

Comment: @StefanoVenneri Are you getting only single row with `fiscalCode` column as value 100?

Comment: Can you show a sample dataset that produces these results?  This would be a strange bug, is it possible that the data changes in between the time when you retrieve the list and then check the details?

Comment: @StefanoVenneri Try to use acute symbol (`) with status.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there is no bug involved , your probably interpret your data in the wrong way. Perhaps the same fiscalCode may appear in multiple records, one with toUpdate = 1 and another with toUpdate = 0. Without seeing a sample data it is impossible to tell.